# Why does .str.contains() not find partial matches here? (Pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, string, pandas, string-matching, partial-matches

Pandas dataframe "df1" has a column ("Receiver") with string values.

```
df1
    Receiver
44  BANK
106 restaurant
149 Tax office
63  house
55  car insurance
```

I want to go through each row of that column, check if they match with values (mostly one- or two-word search terms) in another dataframe ("df2") and return the matching column's title on the correct rows. I'm trying to do it with the following function:

```
df1.Receiver.apply(lambda x:
                               ''.join([i for i in df2.columns 
                               if df2.loc[:,i].str.contains(x).any()]) 
                               )
```

**Problem:** 
However, this *only works* for values in df1's "Receiver" column that consist of **just one word** (so "BANK", "restaurant" and "house" work in this case).

**Values with two or more words do not work** ("Tax office" and "car insurance" in this case).

Isn't str.contains() supposed to find also partial matches? How can I find partial matches also for values in the "Receiver" column that have two or more words?

edit: here's how df2 looks like, it has different categories as column titles, and then each column has the search terms as values

```
df2
    Banks    Restaurants   Car           House
0   BANK     restaurant    car           house
1   bank     mcdonalds     
2            Subway
```

Here is the whole problem in a single image, the output can be seen on the right, and **categories "Car" and "Tax office" are not found because the receivers "car insurance" and "Tax office"** (receiver column in df1) are only **partial matches with the search terms "car" and "Tax"** (values in df2's columns "Car" and "Tax office".
[image]

Comment: what's `df2`? this code doesn't run without that

Comment: I added an example of df2 in the question

Comment: Please post the desired output.

Comment: I posted an image that shows the problem. Desired output (bottom right corner) would include "Tax office" in row 2 and "Car" in row 4.

Comment: If you add another row to `df2` containing the missing items I think it will work.  Note that `"Tax office"` is not contained in `"Tax"`.

Comment: But "Tax" is in "Tax office", I maybe explained unclearly, but df2 has the search terms for each category. Each category is one column title (like "Car" or "Tax office"), and then that category's search terms are that column's values (like "car" or "Tax"). I want to check if there are matches between df2 and the receivers in df1, and in case of a match, show the receiver's respective category (df2's column title for the matching search term)

Comment: And I should add that partial match must be enough, so that "Tax" from df2 would match with "Tax office" as a receiver in df1, and "car" in df2 would match with receiver "car insurance".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating your dataframe rows, you can iterate columns of `df2` and use regex with [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Receiver': ['BANK', 'restaurant house', 'Tax office', 'mcdonalds car']})

df1['Receiver_new'] = ''
for col in df2:
    values = '|'.join(df2[col].dropna())
    bool_series = df1['Receiver'].str.contains(values)
    df1.loc[bool_series, 'Receiver_new'] += f'{col}|'

print(df1)

#            Receiver        Receiver_new
# 0              BANK              Banks|
# 1  restaurant house  Restaurants|House|
# 2        Tax office                    
# 3     mcdonalds car    Restaurants|Car|
```